# Stop blank cells entering into listbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a listbox which is populated with a range of cells but unfortunately some of the cells are blank. In some cases my listbox is getting populated with a large number of cells so it would not be practical to enter each cell manually. Below shows the line of code that populates the listbox:

```
Me.ListBox1.List = Sheets("List Names").Range("C1022:C1200").Value
```

but I need a way to loop through the cells and only add cells that have information in them, or is that even possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can loop cells to fill your listbox. You need to do something like:

```
sub jzz
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range

Set myRange = Range("A1:A5")

For Each myCell In myRange
    If myCell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem myCell.Value
    End If
Next myCell
end sub
```